# Adding mean line to two factor boxplot in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I'd like to add a mean line for each of the 6 groups but ggplot adds a group mean line. The plot currently looks like this: [box plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUaO8.png)

```
ggplot(test, aes(Factor1, YVar)) + geom_boxplot(aes(colour=Factor2)) + 
  labs(x="Factor 1", y="Y Var") +
  guides(color=guide_legend("Factor 2"))+
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="errorbar", aes(ymax=..y..,ymin=..y..), 
               width=0.75, linetype="dashed", size=1, color="black")
```

The above is what the code looks like (excluding colors and such).

Can someone help? Apologies in advance for the simple question. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the `Factor2` as a `group` aesthetic in your call to `stat_summary` -- here's a more reproducible example:

```r
library(ggplot2)

# Original boxplot
ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(color = factor(am)))
```

[image]

```r
# With dashed mean line
ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(color = factor(am))) +
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "errorbar", 
               aes(ymax = ..y.., ymin = ..y.., group = factor(am)),
               width = 0.75, linetype = "dashed")
```

[image]

```r
# Use position = position_dodge()
ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(color = factor(am))) +
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "errorbar", 
               aes(ymax = ..y.., ymin = ..y.., group = factor(am)),
               width = 0.75, linetype = "dashed", position = position_dodge())
```

[image]

Created on 2018-04-17 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).